# Android: getting wrong checked radio button text value

Tags: android

I am trying to view specific icons based on the selected radio button using an if statement. 
I didn't want to use a listener since I'm clicking a submit button anyway.

I have 3 buttons: Party, Accident and Other.
When running my code my Log message shows that I always get "other" (else clause) as a checked value, even when it is not.

I have tried so many different ways from many different threads on Stack Overflow but I'm afraid I might be doing something else wrong.
Here is the code:

```
    private void addMarkerToMap() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MapsActivity.this);
    View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialoglayout, null);

    streetname = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.streetname_input);
    title = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.title_input);
    description = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.description_input);
    radioGroup = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
    final int selectedID = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    radioButton = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(selectedID);

    Button addButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.add_button);
    Button cancelButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.cancel_button);

    builder.setView(view);
    final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();

    addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                addMarker(streetname, title, description);
        }
    });

    cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
}

private void addMarker(EditText streetname, EditText title, EditText description) {
    String streetnameText = streetname.getText().toString();
    String titleText = title.getText().toString();
    String descriptionText = description.getText().toString();
    String radioText = radioButton.getText().toString();
    BitmapDescriptor icon; //= BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.standard); //has to have a standard value
    //Log.d("id", "id" + ID);
    Log.d("radioText", "text: " + radioText);

    if(streetnameText.isEmpty() || titleText.isEmpty() || descriptionText.isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "One of the textboxes is empty. Please fill in all textboxes", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        if(radioText.equals("Accident")){
            icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.accident);
        }
        else if(radioText.equals("Party")){
            icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.party);
        }
        else {
            icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.standard);
        }



        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(latlngGlobal)
                .title(titleText)
                .snippet(descriptionText)
                .icon(icon);

        //TODO add new marker
        mMarker =  mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

        // TODO Get location for marker, add to database
    }
}
```

I have also tried using this instead but it's the same result (gives ID of "other"):

```
           if(ID == R.id.accident_radio){
            icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.accident);
        }
        else if(ID == R.id.party_radio){
            icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.party);
        }
        else {
            Log.d("id", "id" + ID);
            icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.standard);
        }
```

Comment: try adding `trim()` on your radioText `toString()`

Comment: @Pztar just tried it but sadly nothing changed it's still returning other :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared radioButton as the selected radio button in the group at that specific time only, you don't do any new declarations for it before calling addMarker(...) so it will always be the same.

Instead of:

```
String radioText = radioButton.getText().toString();
```

Try something like this (but make it nicer):

```
String radioText = ((RadioButton) view.findViewById(((RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup)).getCheckedRadioButtonId())).getText().toString();
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Don't really know what I was thinking.